# Starting Dev Server for Django on windows

Tags: python, django

I installed Python 3.7, it was added to Path during installation, Then installed Django using the command "pip install django" and it got installed. I started a new project with the command "django-admin startproject pyshop ." and it created that folder with some .py files in it. Then I tried to run the dev server with the command "py manage.py runserver" and I get the response "Unable to create process using 'C:\Users\Prince M\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python.exe manage.py runserver'" in my terminal. What can I do to fix this because this is what I am supposed to do even according to the django documentation.

Comment: ate you able to just run the pytjon interpreter using `C:\Users\Prince M\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python.exe`?

Comment: Did you try both > python manage.py runserver and >python3 manage.py runserver?

Comment: Yes I tried all 3 commands, the one starting with "py manage.py runserver", "python manage.py runserver" and "python3 manage.py runserver" only the first one actually gave the error. the others just returned nothing. Then for being able to run the python interpreter using that path, I don't know how that path came about. my project is in "C:\Users\Prince M\PycharmProjects\PyShop>" then when creating it I selected my interpreter and then run the commands and here I am.

Comment: What do you get when you type python --version in the command prompt?

Comment: When I type "python --version" it's just returning but when I use "py --version" its saying "Python 3.7.7"

Comment: Try C:\Program Files\Python37\python.exe manage.py runserver  .. Make sure you're in your Django project folder where manage.py is located.. Do you get anything different?